# If 8 workers finish the work for 12 days, for how many days the same work will be finished from 4 workers?

Tags: linear-algebra

If 8 workers finish the work for 12 days, for how many days the same work will be finished 
from 4 workers?

I think that the correct answer is 24 days but in a book where I copied this question the correct question that is marked is 6.

Thank you

Comment: BTW, $\,24\,$ days is the correct answer...

Comment: @Enve: Even before starting to solve anything, that answer doesn't make any sence: more workers should do the job in less time (unless the additional 4 workers just prevent the others from working...)

Comment: Depends on the kind of work. If the work is to wash every worker, $4$ workers will still take $12$ days. If the work is to shake every other worker's hand, $4$ workers will only take $\frac{3}{7}\cdot 12$ days.

Comment: @DennisGulko did you mean sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

(1) In one day eight workers do $\,1/12$-th of the total work, so each workers does

$$\frac{\frac{1}{12}}{8}=\frac{1}{96}\,\text{- th of the work each day}$$

(2) Four workers thus do

$$4\frac{1}{96}=\frac{1}{24} -\text{- th of the work each day}$$

so how many days do they need to *finish* the work?

The above is the general setting for these problems. In the present case there is, of course, a much simpler approach: $\,4\,$ workers will finish the work in twice the time as $\,8\,$ workers...

Comment: this is a university sample... look at the 9 question https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByK43DGHmBeYVlFYNmFGRVRqdFk/edit

Comment: Well, I guess anyone can call anything "university" or whatever exercises. The ones in that link are junior high school and high school mathematics, perhaps (and hopefully!) for people who is *not going* to study sciences in that university.

Comment: you are right, this is a test to get merit scholarship and issued by the university, that was the reason I called it "university". I didn't said that the mathematical tasks are for university students